# How to show actual values of javascript variables in a test div?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a 2-player boardgame with a lot of (changing) variables.
For testing purposes, I want to show all these javascripts variables inside a testdiv, like:

```
<div id="testdiv" style="margin-top:800px;background-color:yellow">
/** here the listing of js vars and arrays */
</div>
```

This boardgame uses a backend-file for updating the game, but i get lost when trying to follow what happens exactly with the javascript vars. 
I do know the names of the vars and arrays.
After change of turn, i refresh the page, but I want to update the page via ajax (jQuery).
For checking the playersturn, i already use jQuery and the taconite plugin form http://www.malsup.com/jquery/taconite/
This plugin returns xml, like this:

```
### Taconite output 
?><taconite> 
<?php 
echo $content_refresh; // refresh pagina indien nodig
echo $content_redirect;
echo $content_melding; // melding over verlaten tafel of afgewezen!
echo $content_inpartij; // tegenstander in partij??
echo $content_chataangevraagd; // chat door tegenstander aangevraagd?
echo $content_wachtopaanschuiven; // div leegmaken zodra 2e speler in partij is
echo $content_starttijd;
?>
</taconite>
```

Al content vars are generated xml, for example

```
## Taconite: refresh nodig??

if($refresh_needed == 'ja')
{
$content_refresh = '<eval><![CDATA[
                                 window.location="http://www.xxxxxxxx.nl/v45/partij.php?gameID='.$_GET['gameid'].'";
                    ]]> 
                    </eval>';
//$meta_refresh = '<replaceContent select="#refresh"><META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh"     CONTENT="0"></META></replaceContent>';
}
```

So, instead of refreshing I just want to update the boardgame, but just have not an overview of al (known) present javascript values.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with your plugin nor is your serverside technology listed (guessing php) so I would say take a look at the json serialization abilities of php at http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Then what you should be doing here is in the javascript on the client side, make an ajax request like you are, but have the server side code written using json to send down just the data that represents either the necessary changes or the whole board state. On the client side the JSON object will be recieved and usable as a direct javascript object which you can then have a method that processes it to manually update the board state based on the data the server sent down.

edit:

Sorry, forgot the scope was to get debug information here, for that the method which renders an update to the board, should also render said debug info into a separate div on the screen somewhere. I would use jquery for the ajax if you aren't already, and with jquery you can use the selectors to do:

```
$("#debugDiv").text("Var a: " + boardState.VarA);
$("#debugDiv").append("Var b: " + boardState.VarB);
```

Take a look at:

http://api.jquery.com/append/

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: How do you use javascript to show an overview of the current values of the variables for debug purposes?

Comment: Jimmy thanks for your answer, JSON will cost less data then xml, so i will certainly check this out. Apperantly I was not clear enough about my real question: how to display all my vars/arrays with the actual values,  inside my testdiv, espcially after changing these values. And yes, I use PHP and jQuery:)

Comment: Robert, i populate the JS vars/arrays with PHP and just look inside the generated javascript for the values, but that way, i do not see the changes. I also use Firebug to see what my server sends.

Comment: @Terradon the reason I mentioned JSON is because it will give you data in a format which your javascript can already easily use to print data to the test div with. With the XML response you have to update the entire contents of your board I presume and would then have to parse the XML to get the exact board values. The JSON is treated like a javascript object already which will have your debug values immediately available.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript the variables that you declare `globally` are usually attached to the `window object`. So if your variables are in `global` Scope you can check them in `DOM tab` of `firebug`, and click on `window`.

The problem is that you will see a lot of other variables also there.

If your variables are in some other scope you can just check what is inside the particular scope.

If you want to print them in a div, you will need some way to distinguish your variables from other variables and then use a `for in` loop along with `hasOwnProperty` and `typeof`.

That being said, the best way is to restructure your application so that its atleast transparent to you.